# Use ASIHTTPRequest as NSDictionary Key

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, asihttprequest

I'm attempting to use a `ASIHTTPRequest/ASIFormDataRequest` as a key in a NSDictionary as so:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:GPUserData.userlogin forKey:@"username"];
[request setPostValue:GPUserData.password forKey:@"password"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[_delegates setObject:delegate forKey:request];
[_selectors setObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:selector] forKey:request];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

But, it doesn't return the right data (`nil`s or random) when I try to access `[_delegate objectForKey:request]` from within `-requestFinished:`, so I'm using as a temp solution:

```
[_delegates setObject:delegate forKey:[request url]];
[_selectors setObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:selector] forKey:[request url]];
```

But `[request URL]` isn't unique per individual request.  I know that for something to be a viable key, [it needs to have `-hash` and `-isEqual:` return the same result](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=73), i.e. if the objects return `YES` to `-isEqual:` then they must both return the same from `-hash`.

From `ASIFormDataRequest : ASIHTTPRequest : NSOperation : NSObject` I can see no method that overrides `-isEqual:` or `-hash` from `NSObject` and `ASIHTTPRequest` implements `(NSCopying)` protocol.

So what gives?  Why can't I use the request as a key?  Is there some other unique identifier for the request that I can use?

Any help is appreciated.  For full reference, I'm trying to implement a double-tier callback where the `WebServices` class parses the data on `-requestFinished` (and handles network errors and re-logins) and then makes another callback so just the JSON data gets sent as a `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Are you sure it's the key that's the problem? What is `selector`?

Comment: @Josh Caswell, yeah, selector is `@selector(methodOnDelegate:)`.  It shows up fine, and works when i use `[request url]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you instead store a unique value into request.tag, or use the userinfo dictionary to store the data you need to store? eg:

```
request.userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value", @"key", nil];
```

Comment: WOW.  I did not know about `userInfo`.  Thanks!!  I feel silly now.